# Localize Number and Date Formats but not numeric symbols

Tags: java, locale, number-formatting, date-format

I have a use case where I want to display the dates and numbers based on the user locales.

I am using DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, locale) and NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale) respectively.

The problem I am facing is that, The DateFormat and NumberFormat are changing the numerals based on locale as well, which is not what I want. The want the final String to be using Arabic numerals only (0-9).

For eg,

For a value, 53.54
in hi_IN, it becomes ५३.५४

in de_DE, it becomes 53,54

Whereas I want it to be like,

in hi_IN,  53.54

in de_DE,  53,54

Whether to use . or , as decimal seperator should be based on locale but the numeral should be arabic.
Facing similar issue in Date conversion.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `DateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I cannot reproduce. On my Oracle Java 9 I get 53.54 with locale hi_IN.

Answer (score 1):

While I have not been able to reproduce the behaviour you describe, I *can* show you how to control the digits that a formatter uses.

```
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    if (nf instanceof DecimalFormat) {
        DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) nf;

        // Hindi digits
        char ch0 = '\u0966'; // Hindi zero
        DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = df.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
        symbols.setZeroDigit(ch0);
        df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
        System.out.println(nf.format(53.54));

        // Western digits
        symbols.setZeroDigit('0'); // Western zero
        df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
        System.out.println(nf.format(53.54));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Cannot control digits for this formatter");
    }
```

On my computer output from this snippet is:

> ```
> ५३.५४
> 53.54
> ```

We only specify the zero digit, the char to be used for 0. The formatter figures out the other digits itself from it.

For formatting a date I very warmly recommend java.time, the modern Java date and time API, and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT).withLocale(Locale.GERMAN);

    // Hindi digits
    DecimalStyle style = dateFormatter.getDecimalStyle().withZeroDigit(ch0);
    DateTimeFormatter hindiDateFormatter = dateFormatter.withDecimalStyle(style);
    System.out.println(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Vienna")).format(hindiDateFormatter));

    // Western digits
    style = dateFormatter.getDecimalStyle().withZeroDigit('0');
    DateTimeFormatter westernDateFormatter = dateFormatter.withDecimalStyle(style);
    System.out.println(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Zurich")).format(westernDateFormatter));
```

> ```
> १२.१२.१९
> 12.12.19
> ```

The `DateFormat` class that you tried to use in the question is notoriously troublesome and long outdated.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.